# Remove several functions from Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function App, with many functions inside:

[image]

I need to remove some functions from this Azure Function App. How to do it? "Delete function" option is disabled

Comment: Are you the Azure DevOps CI/CD to deploy your functions? Because my old functions get deleted where the Function App is being automatically deployed...

Comment: yes, I think so...

Comment: Have you tried stopping the Function App and then delete the Functions?

Comment: I even can't get list of functions when Function App is stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a solution, probably, it would be interesting for other:

1. go to Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com), select your Function
   App
2. select `Platform features` tab

[image]

3. select `Kudu` from feature list:

[image]

4. select `Debug Console` -> `CMD`, then go to `site/wwwroot` and delete unnecessary functions:

[image]

5. Stop/Start Function App.
6. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

You couldn't delete your function because your Function app edit mode is `Read Only`, your manage page would be like this:

[image]

So your need go to Function app settings page, switch the edit mode to `Read/Write`, then you will be able to delete the function.

[image]
[image]